# Can someone explain this piece of code to me I need people who know python for loops

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    print (a)
```

Please explain why `i` is mentioned, what does it do in this piece of code?

Comment: I'd recommend reading a tutorial: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. In this case `i` doesn't do anything, it's never used, so the convention would be to use `_` as the loop variable name instead.

Comment: A simple google search should do it. But, i basically is a variable which iterates through all the values in the targetted object, in this case a `list`.

To understand it you should `print(i)`, not `print(a)`.

Comment: The Python for statement iterates over the members of a sequence (that is either a list, a tuple, a dictionary, a set, or a string)  executing the block each time. With the for loop we can execute a set of statements, once for each item in a list, tuple, set etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the **a** by **i** in the print like this :

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 for i in a:
     print (i)

Out[1] : 1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

I recommende you this tutorial to learn about python loops : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Thanks you've helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can write anything in place of `i`.
You can even write the code as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for numbers in a:
    print (numbers)
```

and this should work fine as well. Hope this helped